# Como localizar próximos valores de um mesmo cliente

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Se puderem me ajudar em mais essa e acho que vai servir pra outros também.
Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar em pesquisar os Textbox são preenchidos com os dados do cliente, e clicando novamente no botão Pesquisar os TextBox são carregados com os dados do próximo registro do mesmo cliente.
Ou seja, vai de registro em registro do mesmo código.

Estou com dificuldades no Loop.

```
Private Sub cmdPequisar_Click()
'Verificar se foi digitado um nome na primeira caixa de texto
If txtCPF.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Digite o CPF de um cliente"
txtCPF.SetFocus
GoTo Linha1
End If

With Worksheets("Dados Clientes").Range("A:A")
Set c = .Find(txtCPF.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

Do Until Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = ""
If Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = txtCPF Then

If Not c Is Nothing Then

c.Activate
txtCPF.Value = c.Value
txtNome.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
txtEndereco.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
cboEstado.Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
cboCidade.Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
txtTelefone.Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
txtEmail.Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
txtNascimento.Value = c.Offset(0, 7).Value
Exit Sub

   Linha = Linha + 1

Loop

Else
MsgBox "Cliente não encontrado!"
End If
End With
Linha1:

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme Lima, sou bem novato não me atentei quando copiei o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ludehenrique2cia, repare que há instruções que não serão acessadas após o "**Exit Sub**", como no trecho copiado abaixo:

Exit Sub

Linha = Linha + 1

...

O "**Exit Sub**" faz sair da rotina neste ponto, então as instruções que estiverem após ele na sequência natural desta parte do código não serão executadas (no caso acima, `Linha = Linha + 1` nunca será executada).

Comment: Obrigado Leo, fiz a alteração mas continua a mensagem "Erro de compilação" (Loop sem Do). não entendo porque já coloquei o Do Until

Comment: Ok, mas ai é outro problema, por favor, marque esta resposta que te serviu e crie outra questão com o novo problema.

Comment: Lude, se esta resposta te serviu, é de praxe marcá-la, não há descrição do problema que relatou depois na pergunta original, por isso cada questão deve ser distinta. É praxe também votar nas perguntas e respostas, incluindo as respostas que damos, não entendi o motivo de desmarcar esta resposta se te serviu ou foi útil de alguma forma.

Comment: Só corrigi, foi útil mas não resolveu. é para que outros possam ajudar também. Obrigado!

Comment: Lude, por favor, volte a remarcar esta tanbém amigo, grato.

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
Private Sub cmdPequisar_Click()

    'Verificar se foi digitado um nome na primeira caixa de texto
    If txtcpf.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Digite o CPF de um cliente"
        txtcpf.SetFocus

        Exit Sub

    End If

    With Worksheets("Dados Clientes").Range("A:A")

        Set c = .Find(txtcpf.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

        Do Until Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = ""

            If Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = txtcpf Then

                If Not c Is Nothing Then

                    c.Activate
                    txtcpf.Value = c.Value
                    txtNome.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    txtEndereco.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    cboEstado.Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    cboCidade.Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    txtTelefone.Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    txtEmail.Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
                    txtNascimento.Value = c.Offset(0, 7).Value

                    Exit Do

                    Linha = Linha + 1
                End If
            End If

        Loop

    End With

    If Trim$(txtcpf.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cliente não encontrado!"
    End If

End Sub
```