# Mensagem "Erro de compilação" (Loop sem Do)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Não entendo porque já coloquei o Do Until!

```
Private Sub cmdPequisar_Click()
    'Verificar se foi digitado um nome na primeira caixa de texto   
    If txtCPF.Text = "" Then   
        MsgBox "Digite o CPF de um cliente"   
        txtCPF.SetFocus   
        GoTo Linha1   
    End If

    With Worksheets("Dados Clientes").Range("A:A")   
        Set c = .Find(txtCPF.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)    

        Do Until Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = ""   
            If Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = txtCPF Then

               If Not c Is Nothing Then

                    c.Activate   
                    txtCPF.Value = c.Value   
                    txtNome.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value   
                    txtEndereco.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value   
                    cboEstado.Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value   
                    cboCidade.Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value   
                    txtTelefone.Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value   
                    txtEmail.Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value   
                    txtNascimento.Value = c.Offset(0, 7).Value   

                    Linha = Linha + 1

            Loop

            Exit Sub   

        Else   

            MsgBox "Cliente não encontrado!"   

        End If   
    End With   

    Linha1:   

    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro? Não seria melhor indentar o código?

Comment: Duplicada, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137590/como-localizar-pr%C3%B3ximos-valores-de-um-mesmo-cliente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
Do

  ...
  ...

Loop Until Sheets("Dados Clientes").Cells(0, 1) = ""
```

Na frente do DO não coloque nada.

Comment: Não deixe de "identar" seus códigos, ficam todos difíceis de analisar sem a identação! Não esqueça de votar (veja a ajuda do site)